# SOLR - split string field into list

Tags: indexing, split, solr

In Solr 8.9, I want to index string field as list by splitting it.

It works partially.

If my source string is `A|B|C`.

After indexing, the Solr output is :

```
"field": ["A|B|C", "A", B", "C"]
```

I would like it to be :

```
"field": ["A", B", "C"]
```

Could someone explain me, why I have in my multivalued field, the source string and the splitted string ?

My `data_config.xml`

```
<document> 
    <entity name="items" 
        query="SELECT Id, Structures FROM Items"
        transformer="RegexTransformer"
    > 
        <field column="structures" splitBy="\|" sourceColName="Structures" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

Below is the field definition in `schema.xml` file

```
<field name="structures" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Its looks like regular expression issue. Have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/DataImportHandler#DataImportHandler-RegexTransformer# and try to debug

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved after changing my column name.

My query in `data_config.xml` :

```
query="SELECT Id, Structures as structures FROM Items"
```

The field definition in `schema.xml` file

```
<field column="structures" splitBy="\|" sourceColName="structures" />
```